# how to convert this to switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

```java
if(x > -1 && x <1)  
  System.out.println("x is between -1 to 1");  
else if (x==5)  
  System.out.println("x is 5");  

else  
  System.out.println("x is some other values");
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm thinking it's an incorrect tagging. My guess is they actually meant Java, but I'm unsure.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

A switch statement can be used only when the value a variable takes is definite, not a range of values.Assuming you could take input as only integers.
So you could do it as:

```
switch(x):

{

case 5:

System.out.println("x is 5");

break;


case -1:

System.out.println("x is -1");

break;

case 1:

System.out.println("x is 1");

break;

default:

System.out.println("x is some other value");

break;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch here even with float or double value with following trick

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double value = 5.234;
    int absValue;

    if((int) Math.abs(value / 1) == 5 )
    {
        absValue = value == 5 ? 5 : 20; // if value is not exactly 5 then absValue should set to any value which is not 5 and not between -1 and 1
    }
    else
    {
        absValue = (int) Math.abs(value / 1) ;
    }

    switch (absValue)
    {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("x is between -1 and 1");
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("x is 5");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("x is some other value");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` is an `int`, the only way for it to be between `-1` and `1` is if it's `0`, so there are just three cases in the `switch` statement:

```
switch (x) {
    case 0:
    System.out.println("x is between -1 and 1");
    break;

    case 5:
    System.out.println("x is 5");  
    break;

    default:
    System.out.println("x is some other value");
}
```